# How can I use Sidekiq delay with a worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a situation where I have a worker that makes multiple calls to an external API. The problem is that we have a threshold of many calls we can make to this API per hour.

What I'd like to do is to create a worker which will make these many sequential calls to this external API. If in between these calls we get an error because we've reached the number of connections we're allowed in that hour, the worker would then save the document and schedule a new worker to complete the remaining API calls at a later time (maybe 1, 2 hours later. Ideally this should be configurable e.g.: 10mins, 1hour, etc).

Is there someway I could achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Right now this question is pretty open.

Comment: You can use a worker like 'Delayed Job' . This gem allow you to schedule your worker. Please check this link https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With SideKiq you can scheduled when a job will be executed with a friendly API :

```
MyWorker.perform_in(3.hours, 'mike', 1) # Expect a duration
MyWorker.perform_at(3.hours.from_now, 'mike', 1) # Expect a date
```

Check it out : [Scheduled Jobs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs)

Answer (score 2):

You want Sidekiq Enterprise and its Rate Limiting API.  The alternative is tracking the rate limit yourself and rescheduling the job manually.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Ent-Rate-Limiting